# Tracking file system events in a directory using FSEventStreamCreate is not working as I expect

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to avoid running a timer and would like to use the `FSEventStreamCreate` to advise the application when database files have been modified. I am getting the results I want in the application by including `NSHomeDirectory()` in the array of paths to check but only because the home directory is so busy. If I exclude `NSHomeDirectory()` or if for some reason a machine was not as busy as mine the application would not trap changes to the database files often enough.

The following code works only once every time I start a debugging session.

```
-(void) initializeEventStream
{

    NSString *databaseDirectoryPath = @"/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Databases/development";
    NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory() ;

    NSArray *pathsToWatch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:databaseDirectoryPath,  homeDirectoryPath, nil];
    void *appPointer = (void *)self;
    FSEventStreamContext context = {0, appPointer, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    NSTimeInterval latency = 3.0;

    self.fileSystemEventStreamRef = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                 &fsevents_callback,
                                 &context,
                                 (CFArrayRef) pathsToWatch,
                                 [self.lastEventIDNumber unsignedLongLongValue],
                                 (CFAbsoluteTime) latency,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes
                                 );

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(self.fileSystemEventStreamRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    FSEventStreamStart(self.fileSystemEventStreamRef);
}
```

Any ideas on how to make `FSEventStreamCreate` more responsive for

```
NSString *databaseDirectoryPath = @"/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Databases/development";
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
-(void) initializeEventStream
{

    NSString *databaseDirectoryPath = @"/Library/FileMaker\ Server/Data/Databases/development";
    NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory() ;

    NSArray *pathsToWatch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:databaseDirectoryPath,  homeDirectoryPath, nil];
    void *appPointer = (void *)self;
    FSEventStreamContext context = {0, appPointer, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    NSTimeInterval latency = 1.0;

    self.fileSystemEventStreamRef = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                             &fsevents_callback,
                             &context,
                             (CFArrayRef) pathsToWatch,
                             kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                             (CFAbsoluteTime) latency,
                             kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot
                             );

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(self.fileSystemEventStreamRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),     kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    FSEventStreamStart(self.fileSystemEventStreamRef);
}
```